# What will be effect of using static variable or final static varibale on permormance

Tags: java, android, static, garbage-collection, final

I am new in the world of android. i am developing an android app where i need to use some static field and some final static field. As it concern with performance of application.i have done search on this topic

1.what will be effect on memory and performance

2.How garbage collection work while handling with static or final static field.

3. When these field available for garbage collection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1)There's no perf penalty for a variable being static.  It will take the same amount of memory as a non static variable.

2/3)A variable in a static field cannot be garbage collected unless the class itself is kicked out of memory.  In practical terms, it will never happen.  TO have it be collected, you'd need to overwrite the variable to another value (which would then be uncollectable) or null.

Static final fields are constants.  They can't be overwritten, so they will never be collected.

Comment: Not all `static final` variables are constants. They have to be initialized with a constant expression to be constants, per the JLS. That means they must be primitives or `String`s. They are compiled into the code as literals. Not all non-constant `static finals` can be treated as constants; they may be mutable. Non-`static` variables can be constants, whether members or local. Only constants and `final` variables for immutable objects should be treated as constants, including getting names in all uppercase with underscores.

Comment: Being mutable doesn't mean they aren't constant-  the REFERENCES are constant.  Of course the data it references can be changed if the class allows it.  Totally different concept.  Just like a const pointer in C++ can still have the data pointed at changed unless its typename const * const

Comment: @LewBloch  For this  i had made a separate class to hold all static final field and initialize with constant expression  i.e     public static final String CUSTOMER_EDIT_USER_ID="CUSTOMER_EDIT_USER_ID";  . My question was how it will affect in memory and corresponding to performance of application and when static final or static field available for garbage collection

Comment: @Gabe Sechan Yes, being mutable means not constant, because by definition constant variables are either primitives or `String`s. Also, even a looser definition of "constant" not in accordance with the JLS should not be a synonym for `final`. Notionally "constant" is something whose value is fixed, and refers to the object, not the reference. A mutable `final` reference is not thread-safe after construction, for example, and this is one property we seek in a "constant". Another is that all uses will see the object in the same state. If the state isn't constant, it violates the idea.

Comment: @LewBloch Yeah, I think I'll just go on using the same version of the word constant that's existed for the past 30 years.  A constant reference/pointer is a constant, regardless of if the object it points to is mutable or not.  Unless you're going to claim a const char* is non-constant, which of course would get you laughed out of the room.

Comment: `const char *` is not Java, is it? I think I'd be "laughed out of the room" for trying to make a point about Java using a construct that doesn't exist in Java. Read the JLS; a constant variable is a `final` variable initialized by a _constant expression_.

Comment: No, its an older language.  Which has the idea of concepts and predates Java, as did a dozen other languages.  You don't get to just reterm basic CS concepts.  If you want to talk about the idea of mutable objects, call it mutability.  A constant variable like final is still a constant.  All you're doing is adding confusion by trying to rebrand something.  You're just wrong.  Discussion over.

Comment: When I'm working with Java, I use the vocabulary appropriate to the Java language. The term "constant" is a term of art defined in the JLS. Don't get mad at me; I didn't have anything to do with writing the JLS.

Comment: And "discussion over" is neither logic nor evidence.

Comment: No, it means I'm done having an argument over basic computer science terms.  Constant means a value doesn't change.  The value here is the reference.  It does not mean immutability of the referred object.  If you want to change it, build a time machine to the 60s and introduce the concept then.  Until then, a final value is a constant.